# Is it possible to get native element for formControl?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I've got Angular [reactive form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html). I created `formControl`s and assigned it to input fields by`[formControl]=...`. As I understand it creates `nativeElement <-> formControl` link.

My question: is it possible to get `nativeElement` for `formControl`? I want to do something like `myFormControl.nativeElement.focus()`

Comment: Can you show some code? Tell us where and how you want it?

Comment: updated question description

Comment: But when you want to focus it? that is imp.

Comment: Do you have one or multi formControls?

Answer (score 22):

The code below does not work with pure ngModel binding, so I did a lot of experiments. Latest, also confirmed by Maximillian Schwarzmuller should be the one:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel], [formControl]', // or 'input, select, textarea' - but then your controls won't be handled and also checking for undefined would be necessary
})
export class NativeElementInjectorDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl, @Optional() private model : NgModel) {
        if (!! model)
            (<any>model.control).nativeElement = el.nativeElement;
        else
            (<any>control).nativeElement = el.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

So if this directive is provided and exported in the main module, **it will attach a custom nativeElement property to all FormControl**.

It's a shame it's not coming out-of-the box...

Comment: the usage is unclear, does it automatically provide nativeElement property if you just simply import export that directive to the main module? my formcontrol cannot recognize the property and there is no suggestion for property completion/prediction. It would be better to post how to use your directive

Comment: @Shift'NTab regardelss if it's my or others or angulars directive, they're used the same way.

if you declare the directive in a custom module, you need to import it into the module where you want to use it.

or just declare it in your module and add the class into the declarations array of the module.

once there it'll auto execute. you can put a debugger into the ctor if U don't believe.

Comment: I did the instruction as exactly as you said, maybe you need to use ngModel to FormControl?

Comment: @Shift'NTab since it's a [ngModel] directive, you are probably right. so yes, you could also extend this to FormControl as well (nfFormControl or formControl - would need to check).

Since I find the react way awkward and all these details were needed to have template driven way approach with 3rd party validation to work, I do focus just on ngModel... But as I said, it's just an additional selector what U need.

Comment: @Shift'NTab so, in short: create amodule where you implement (declare) the directive and make sure you also export it. then just include the module where you need it. that's it.

Comment: ok back here again the `(<any>control.control).nativeElement` has a bug because control.control in the console returns undefined. Which prevents you to assign a dynamic property.

Comment: @Shift'NTab I have this in my project and it simply works. Although haven't tested it for custom controls with ngModel.

** Can you create a plunker so I can check the issue? **

Also you could assign the nativeElement prop to the NgControl itself, but later on in your code the FormControl is what U got access to.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it work by importing this directive into main module. But it worked when I've imported&declared it in that particular module that contained the component where I needed to use this directive.

Comment: @baHI your code looks good, but I've tested it in Angular 8 and it seems it doesn't work, the property NgControl.control doesn't exist. Please have a look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-every-htm-element-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnative-element-directive.ts 
Do you know how could this code be adapted to Angular 8? Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoX updated https://stackoverflow.com/a/49462046/4524989, so it should work now, the issue was that original sample was for template driven approach, where NgModel was injected into the control, whereas with model driven you get directyl the NgControl of the given input. just check out the update. Btw. thanx for the StackBlitz, and sorry that it took 5 days (had much work) :) Use that debugging, it helped me a lot...

Comment: @DenysAvilov 's comments helped me, thank you for pointing out the importing module matters.

Comment: I was able to create and declare the directive in a library module and import it in my main app's module that containing the component need to use the directive.

Answer (score 12):

I can share one terrible solution but it works for me.

In reactive forms we can use either

**1) FormControlDirective**

**ts**

```typescript
myControl = new FormControl('')
```

**template**

```typescript
<input type="text" [formControl]="myControl">
```

or

**2) FormControlName**

**ts**

```typescript
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    foo: ''
  });
}
```

**template**

```typescript
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
</form>
```

So for these directives i could write some patch like

**1) FormControlDirective**

```typescript
const originFormControlNgOnChanges = FormControlDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges;
FormControlDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges = function() {
  this.form.nativeElement = this.valueAccessor._elementRef.nativeElement;
  return originFormControlNgOnChanges.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

**2) FormControlName**

```typescript
const originFormControlNameNgOnChanges = FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges;
FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges = function() {
  const result =  originFormControlNameNgOnChanges.apply(this, arguments);
  this.control.nativeElement = this.valueAccessor._elementRef.nativeElement;
  return result;
};
```

After that we can easily access to native element having `FormControl` instance

**1) FormControlDirective**

```typescript
focusToFormControl() {
  (<any>this.myControl).nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**2) FormControlName**

```typescript
focusToFormControlName(name) {
  (<any>this.myForm.get(name)).nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WII8VvHB5iGbPWB2CcM3?p=preview)**

Comment: hi, i exactly added the prototype on top of my component class but i get an error that `this.valueAccessor._elementRef` is undefined in `FormControlName`.

Answer (score 11):

Added minor fix to baHI answer(moved logic to OnInit). Error mentioned in comments is probably connected to changes in forms. This answer is for "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[ngModel]'
    })
    export class NativeElementInjectorDirective implements OnInit {
        constructor (private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) {}

        ngOnInit(){
          (this.control.control as any).nativeElement = this.el.nativeElement;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works for us on angular 6 :D only change needed was "selector: [formControlName]" Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to write Directive with `[formControl], [formControlName]` selector.
Full example:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
   selector: '[formControl], [formControlName]'
})
export class ControlErrorsDirective {
    get control() {
       return this.controlDir.control;
    }

    constructor(
        private controlDir: NgControl,
        private host: ElementRef<HTMLFormElement>) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.host.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

and in your html just use `formControlName` like this:`<input formControlName='name' />`

Extra Note: I use this code to add dynamic error message for each form control.

Comment: I use this code to add dynamic error message for each form control.

Comment: how do you get the native element related to the form control if you don't link them?

Comment: The idea (see my answer - 15 upvotes) is simple: use a directive which simply extends the angular control object with an additional nativeElement property. From that point on, if you reference that control, you will have also access to that property.

But you maybe need just a template reference!?

Comment: why do you need two selector? I found only one selector: ' [formControlName]' worked. An actually selector formControl was not working.

Answer (score 2):

Hello to whoever reads this! I hope you are having as much fun as I am playing with Angular :)

I spent a little time with a related issue that lead me here.
The "injector" directive solution seems to me like a workaround, and an unpredictable way of approaching the problem.

I suspect the Angular team may have their reasons why this isn't "out-of-the-box." Perhaps they don't want to tie a FormControl to an exact DOM element since these two can outlive one another or get removed (in the case of the native element), or get cloned (which would not copy the "extended" assignment and, thus, effectively loosing any assignment from the directive targeting the original DOM element and a previous clone of the FormControl object), etc.

So after some thought, I went with this solution:

```
// Get the first invalid formControlName to scroll to: 
const firstInvalidField = 
  Object.keys(form.controls).find(field => form.get(field)?.invalid);

// My DOM element query selector string
const selector = `[formControlName=${firstInvalidField}]`;

console.log(
  document.querySelector( ${selector} )`
);
```

Now I'm guaranteed that I will have the reference to the DOM Element.

Comment: This solution doesn't support nested formGroups or form control arrays. Thanks for your effort

Comment: @user2599470 that's very reasonable direction .. and totally makes sense. Although document.querySelector feel quite hackish in the context of angular.

Answer (score 2):

Create an input field on template:

```
<input matInput formControlName="cardnumber" #cardnumber >
```

Get the viewchild of it in class:

```
@ViewChild("cardnumber") cardnumberField: FormControl;
```

Init it:

```
this.cardnumberField = new FormControl(null, []);
```

And do with it whatever you want:

```
(<any> this.cardnumberField).nativeElement.value = "";
(<any> this.cardnumberField).nativeElement.focus();
```