# How to do Angular2/4 validation with 3rd party JS components

Tags: angular, validation

When it comes to Angular 2 validation, I saw different approaches. The basic is to use either HTML5 and template/model binding or forms with assigned validators.

However when it comes to special rules it needs a lot of coding and with template binding (so no forms) mostly results in validation being scattered through HTML and TS code.

Also another annoying thing around validation is that you need to alter validation rules in TS and also add extra HTML code to have those values on the page rendered (although this can be automated via directive)...

Anyhow the ideal solution would be to use rules to model properties which then generates error messages to the controls. Similarly to .NET fluent validation and ModelState or in JS world similar to Aurelia.io validation: http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation/

1. Is something similar possible in Angular2+?
2. How/where to wire check  (based on model change) to a 3rd party (JS) library? Like fluent-ts-validator or flient-validator.
3. How to set errors on controls, especially when we have f.e. controls inside
   controls...

Comment: All my concerns on that validation is in detail described here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/angular-templateform-driven-development-validation-balazs-hideghety/

Answer (score 0):

**First thing we will need is to link the FormControls to the input elements.** It's not provided out of the box. The only solution so far (at least for pure ngModel binding) is the one i have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642547/is-it-possible-to-get-native-element-for-formcontrol).

The code below does not work with pure ngModel binding, so I did a lot of experiments. Latest, also confirmed by Maximillian Schwarzmuller should be the one:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel]', // or 'input, select, textarea' - but then your controls won't be handled and also checking for undefined would be necessary
})
export class NativeElementInjectorDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) {
        (<any>control.control).nativeElement = el.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

So if this directive is provided and exported in the main module, **it will attach a custom nativeElement property to all FormControl**.

Answer (score 0):

**Next thing** was to know how to build nested forms properly - see [link here](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)!

And also not just forward **ngForm** but also **ngModelGroup**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'TestAddress',
    templateUrl: './address.location.html',
    viewProviders: [
        { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm },
        { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: forwardRef(() => NgModelGroup) },
    ],
    providers: [ MakeProvider(TestAddress) ]
})
export class TestProspectAddressLocation extends AbstractValueAccessor<any> {
...
}
```

We had to use **AbstractValueAccessor** and thus a MakeProvider too.
[Here's the link](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/)!

**Last piece:** a way to access those FormControls:

```
this.form.get('HomeAddress.City').nativeElement
```

**Now you can subscribe to formValueChange and user 3rd party for validation, access any control by a path expression, use control.setErrors([]) or just append a HTML via jQuery aft. input.**

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for:

1. To create some directive that could add a [(ngModel)] binding to every control which has ngModel attribute and a name defined - whereas the expression assigned should be 'value.' + name attribute value
2. A way to replace a div added by jQuery dynamically with an angular component - and since the div is dynamic, @ViewChild(selector) can't be used
3. Using nested forms with [(ngModel)] binding does produce a weird FormGroup structure, so either the custom angular component should auto-define ngModelGroup='name attr. value' or using ngControlOptions standalone or another way should be foud which does not do a mess...

Answer (score 0):

**So #2 from the list above was possible to do.**

We do use a ngModel selector to get a ref. to all inputs, of course we do have a main control (which contains validation related messages/code) and thus we ignore controls not inside that container.

**Now here comes the trick:** we do get a viewContainerRef to the input itself. This allows us to inject a control immediately after the input. Since injection is to that given viewContainer, when input get's hidden, the injected control is destroyed...

**The code:**

```
import {Directive, OnInit, Optional, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";
import {NgControl} from "@angular/forms";
import {ValidationContainerDirective} from "./validation-container-directive";

/*
This directive should match all inputs (ngModel)...
If it's inside a validation container, it'll process it...
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel]'
})
export class ValidationControlForInjectorDirective implements OnInit {

    private initialized: boolean = false;

    constructor(@Optional() private validationContainer: ValidationContainerDirective,
                private control: NgControl,
                private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              ) {

        // skip if not inside a validation container...
        if (!this.validationContainer)
            return;

        // mark as initialized
        this.initialized = true;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // skip if not initialized
        if (!this.initialized)
            return;

        var thisLocator = this.control.path.join(".");

        // check inputs...
        if (!thisLocator)
            throw new Error('Validation wire issues!');

        // add a control aft. the input...but disable it temporarily...
        this.validationContainer.injectComponent(this.viewContainerRef, thisLocator);
    }

}
```

**The injectComponent method above does just set up my control and attaches it to the viewContainerRef:**

```
injectComponent(componentVcRef: ViewContainerRef, locator: string) {

    // create component
    var componentRef = componentVcRef.createComponent(this.componentFactoryForValidationControlFor);

    // basic set up (switching server/client messages on/off is done by the doCheckManagedComponents() fnc.
    (<ValidationControlFor>componentRef.instance).locator = locator;
    (<ValidationControlFor>componentRef.instance).isDynamic = true;
    (<ValidationControlFor>componentRef.instance).serverMessages = false;
    (<ValidationControlFor>componentRef.instance).clientMessages = false;
    (<ValidationControlFor>componentRef.instance).clientMessagesAlwaysVisible = this.clientMessagesAlwaysVisible;

    componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    // NOTE:
    // registering of managed component is done via the component's ngOnInit function...
    // ...it was moved there, because we need to keep track also of manually added validation-message-controls!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out a framework/library called **ts.validator.fluent**. Generic object validation. Fluent rules.

https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/ts.validator

Also, an **Angular 6 CLI app** to demo the framework:

https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/ts-validator-app-angular6

The app uses a **Service oriented approach to client-side form validation**, with the below advantages:

- The business rules around validation are separated from the components.
- The business rules are centralized in the validation service.
- The service is re-usable.
- The service can be injected into any component.
- You can unit test the business rules by unit testing the service.

**NPM Package**:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts.validator.fluent

Here is an example of how your TypeScript models can be validated using the framework:

```
/* Install npm package ts.validator.fluent and then import like below */
import { IValidator, Validator, ValidationResult } from 'ts.validator.fluent/dist';

/*TypeScript model*/
class Person {
   Name: string;
}

/* Validation rules */
var validatePersonRules = (validator: IValidator<Person>) : ValidationResult => {
  return validator
             .NotEmpty(m => m.Name, "Name cannot be empty")
        .ToResult();
};

/* Populate model */
var person = new Person();
person.Name = "Shane";

/* Validate model */
/* Sync */
var validationResult = new Validator(person).Validate(validatePersonRules); 
/* Async */
var validationResult = await new Validator(person).ValidateAsync(validatePersonRules);
```

Comment: Hi, seems to be very impressive solution. May I ask how you display the results on the angular component?

Comment: @baHi Thanks. The results are shown using ng-bootstrap tooltips in the angular component. But you can display them any how you like.

Comment: i had a lot of work to do that display via an auto injected component, that is able to use angular templates and so on. the validation itself was an easy stuff to do, but the original fluent validator had to be patched to auto-add param names. that one works without extra validation classes, so IMO flexible in cases.

Comment: @baHI ok, mine uses tooltips with a <ul> to display the results. Easy enough to do. Also, mine is a Service oriented approach to form validation. Many advantages to that.