# Angular : When submitting Template Driven form how can I set focus on first invalid input

Tags: angular

I have checked in stackoverflow but I only found the way to do.
I found a solution with `querySelector` but is there any better approach for setting focus?
When I submit the form then I want to set focus on the first invalid input using Template Driven form.

How can I set focus on first invalid input using Template Driven forms?

Comment: use template reference of the input and attach it to a property of elementref  using @viewChild and use this to focus to the element in the dom

Comment: But how to loop for multiple input fields

Comment: do you intend  to focus each invalid element one after the other ?

Comment: @Joel Yes, so thats why i hane multiple input fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Reactive Forms : How to set focus on first invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924414/angular-6-reactive-forms-how-to-set-focus-on-first-invalid-input)

Comment: @Sandy its a `Reactive form` solution i want `Template` driven form way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION # 1:**

I just coded this and it's working at least with inputs (with type text and number) and also with selects. It's using template driven as you requested.

Here it goes:

This is the minimum that you will need in your component (.ts file):

```
// Built-in Packages:
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f', {static: false}) ingredientForm: NgForm;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  focusFirstInvalidControl(): void {
    const formControls = this.ingredientForm.controls;
    const formControlsKeys = Object.keys(formControls)

    for (let i = 0; i < formControlsKeys.length; i++) {
      const isInvalid = formControls[formControlsKeys[i]].invalid;
      if (isInvalid) {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${formControlsKeys[i]}`).focus();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That NgForm is connected as usual to your form on your template.

**Conditions:**

in order to make this work, each input inside the form in your template, needs to have a matching id, with the name and the local reference bindded to ngModel. All of them using the same name/denomination.

**Example:** Using a text input for the "*Name*".

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          name="name"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Type the name here"
          autofocus
          required
          ngModel
          #name="ngModel"
        >
      </div>
      <span *ngIf="(name?.invalid && name.touched); else nameOk" class="help-block">Please enter a valid name</span>
      <ng-template #nameOk><span class="help-block">&nbsp;</span></ng-template>
    </div>
```

**Another example:** Using a numeric input for the "*Amount*":

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="amount"
          name="amount"
          min="1"
          class="form-control"
          required
          [ngModel]="1"
          #amount="ngModel"
        >

      </div>
      <span *ngIf="(amount?.invalid && amount.touched); else amountOk" class="help-block">Please enter a valid amount</span>
      <ng-template #amountOk><span class="help-block">&nbsp;</span></ng-template>
```

Now you only need to trigger the method "*focusFirstInvalidControl*" on the submit event or by any other way that you prefer.

**SOLUTION # 2:**

This is even simpler:

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

      focusFirstInvalidControlPlus(): void {
        const firstElementWithErrors: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`form .ng-invalid`);
        if (firstElementWithErrors) {
          firstElementWithErrors.focus();
        }
      }
```

Just trigger the method "*focusFirstInvalidControlPlus*" within your .ts file on the submit event. It works when using template driven and also with Reactive approach.

Comment: This seems to assume that `id == name` for all form controls, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Indeed. Which is VERY easy to make it the case. That's why is included on the conditions.