# Angular 8 focus on material input from method

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

In my application I'am using Angular 8, reactive forms and material designee.

And in specific case, i need to set focus on one of my input filed from the methods.

While I research I found there was a way to do this with "ElementRef" there was a few example, this is the one of them:
[Angular 6 Reactive Forms : How to set focus on first invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924414/angular-6-reactive-forms-how-to-set-focus-on-first-invalid-input)

On this(or any) ElementRef I couldn't find focus() method(also there is no in the nativeElement.focus()).

Is there a way to this directly on formeControle, or any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it from `formControl`, however you can do it by using template variables in the template or `@ViewChild` in the component.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #myInput>
</mat-form-field>
<-- You can focus from template this way -->
<button (click)="myInput.focus()">Focus</button>
```

To set the focus on component:

```js
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChild('myInput') input: MatInput;

  // You can focus from component this way
  focusMyInputFromComponent() {
     this.input.focus();
  }

}
```

Comment: To set the focus from inside `focusMyInputFromComponent()`, you will need to change your template like this: `<input matInput #myInput="matInput">`

Comment: Do you can direct me to the docs, why this have to be like this? Or explain in short, please?