# Auto focus invalid input inside NgModelGroup when submit form Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

when i submit form, i want to focus into input invalid, code below work for normal input, but with input inside NgModelGroup, it's not working, pls help me, thanks!

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

declare var $: any;
@Directive({ selector: "[accessible-form]" })
export class AccessibleForm {

@Input("form") form: NgForm;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener("submit", ["$event"])
onSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (!this.form.valid) {
  let target = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ng-invalid");

  if (target) {
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target) }, "slow");
    target[0].focus();
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz exaple? it would be much easier to see entire context of your problem

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property `[formControlName]` on your input element and then use query selector :

```
for (const key of Object.keys(this.addressForm.controls)) {
  if (this.addressForm.controls[key].invalid) {
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('[formcontrolname="' + key + '"]');
    invalidControl.focus();
    break;
 }
```

}

See [Angular 6 Reactive Forms : How to set focus on first invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924414/angular-6-reactive-forms-how-to-set-focus-on-first-invalid-input)