# How to get type of form control that is whether it is textbox or checkbox OR get tag name of form control?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to get type of the form control(i.e whether it is textbox or checkbox) OR form control tag name(e.g mat-checkbox or mat-form-field) In my case I am using angular material.

I am using `control.valueChanges(` I wanna know there whether if its textbox or checkbox or if I get tag name like mat-checkbox then also its fine...

data.service.ts

```
saveChanges(control: AbstractControl, url: string, property: string) {
    if (control) {
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(data => {
          this.loaderService.show('Saving', 'Saving...', 'snackbar', 'saving');
          return this.http.patch(url, {
            [property]: data.value || data.value === '' ? data.value : data
          });
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

components.component.ts (if isEdit allowed then only calling formPatch with url)

```
formPatch(url) {
    this.patchSubscription.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
    this.patchSubscription.push(
      this.dataService
        .saveChanges(this.store, url, 'store')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
        .subscribe()
    );
    this.patchSubscription.push(
      this.dataService
        .saveChanges(this.componentType, url, 'componentType')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
        .subscribe()
    );
}
```

Above code is for auto save values on change with debounceTime(2000) 
I want debounceTime only for textbox and textarea controls, rest of of the controls like select(mat-select), checkbox(mat-checkbox) should immediately fire http PATCH.  debounceTime(0) OR no debounceTime

Any idea how to achive this?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This check that you want to do, is just for a single element or you want to check all  `form control`?

Comment: all form controls

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet?

Comment: @buchipper Please check post . I've added code snippet now

Comment: Potentially you can have multiple editor for same form control, so what you are looking for is not the right direction

Comment: Based on my understanding of your question, I think this would solve your problem. Check @baHI's answer. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642547/is-it-possible-to-get-native-element-for-formcontrol